# Regex: Optional followed by a negative lookahead

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have some regex experience but it's been a while. I wrote a complicated expression, trying to match certain patterns in a product code that I identify as being invalid. I ran my code over several thousand codes to validate it, and I've found a couple cases that are not behaving as expected.

I've narrowed it down to one particular issue, which I've presented below in a simplified manner - this is the concept I'm not understanding, not the actual expression I'm using. I want to find codes that start in a certain manner, contain optional components in the middle (but if they do exist, they must exactly match a certain pattern - I can't just greedily match anything), but do not end correctly (should end in "d" but do not). It's being implemented in (gag) VBScript, by the way, through the Windows scripting host.

```
^a(b)?(c)?(?!d$)
```

Things that should match:

- ae
- abe
- ace
- abce

Things that should not match:

- ad
- abd
- acd
- abcd
- afe
- abfe
- acfe
- abcfe

Essentially, "ae" matches correctly, but any time one or both of the optionals should match, it causes the entire match to fail. I think this has to do with the greedy nature of ? but haven't been able to figure out how to get this to work. Again, I can't use something like the below -  if components exist between "a" and "e", they must be exactly "b" or "c".

```
^a(?!.*d$)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I assume that in your real-world example, `d` is more than a single letter. Right?

Comment: Correct -  a, b, c, d, e all represent separate pattern matches, for certain order and number of characters. Individually they work, so I tried to take that complexity out of the question.

Answer (score 7):

I assume that by "fail" you mean that `abd` matches when it shouldn't. First, let's see why that is so:

1. `a` matches `a`
2. `b` matches `(b)?`
3. `d` doesn't match `(c)?`, but OK, it's optional
4. `(?!d$)` fails because we're right before `d` at the end of the string. So this approach won't work. The problem now is that there is another possibility the regex engine hasn't attempted yet, so it backtracks to the position before `b`:
5. Let's try *not* to use `(b)?` to match `b`, since it's optional.
6. `b` also doesn't match `(c)?`. OK, it's optional.
7. `(?!d)` succeeds because we're right before `cd` at the end of the string, and that doesn't match `d$`. Success!

So, what can you do? It would be nice if you could use a [negative lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but alas, ECMAScript regexes don't support that.

The next best way would be to put the negative lookahead at the start of the regex:

```
^(?!.*d$)a(b)?(c)?
```

first makes sure that the string doesn't end with `d`. Only then it starts the actual match. Now this passes all your test cases.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good start - hadn't thought about matching out of order.

Comment: However, though it works on the test cases I presented, I guess my test cases were incomplete. It seems that this would also match "abfe", which is not intended. The match must be to ^a, optionally b|c|bc and nothing else, and not ending with d. I will update the question accordingly.

You're spot on with what I mean by fail, though. I guess I'm not understanding how (c)? is being handled - apparently d gets tested, passes, and the engine continues past d?